# I'm having some problem with setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I want my stopwatch as if 60 seconds complete . There should be an increment in minute and seconds to start from 0 again . I tried so many ways to do so but it always stop working when time is one minute .. is it built in problem in `setInterval()`

```
async timer() {


  var timeout = setInterval(() => {
    count++
    this.timerSecond.innerText = count;
    if (count > 59) {
      count = 0;
      this.timerSecond.innerText = count;
      count1++
      this.timerMinute.innerText = count1

    }
  }, 100);
  console.log(timeout);

  return timeout;
}
```

Comment: Your code has issues. Syntax is invalid.

Comment: Leaving a setInterval 60 times over a requested duration of 1000 milliseconds will always exceed 1 minute, it can give one minute and 10 seconds for example

Comment: @mwilson it's most likely meant to be a class method, considering the `this.prop` references in the arrow functions as well.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this method work for you?

```
timer () {
  let seconds = 0;

  const tick = () => {
    this.timerText.textContent = seconds;
    this.timerSecond.textContent = `${seconds % 60}`.padStart(2, '0');
    this.timerMinute.textContent = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds++;
  };

  tick();
  return setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
```

It's hard to tell why you had two separate `setInterval()` calls, but I removed the one called every 100 milliseconds and combined the logic into a single one.

The `timerSecond` uses modulo 60 of `seconds`, and `timerMinute` uses result of integer division by 60, while the `timerText` just receives the `seconds` directly, as in your initial code.

The `async` keyword didn't add any value to your code, since none of it uses promises, so I removed it.

Here's a slightly elaborated example to demonstrate functionality:

```js
class Stopwatch {
  timerText = document.querySelector('.text');
  timerSecond = document.querySelector('.second');
  timerMinute = document.querySelector('.minute');

  timer () {
    let seconds = 0;

    const tick = () => {
      this.timerText.textContent = seconds;
      this.timerSecond.textContent = `${seconds % 60}`.padStart(2, '0');
      this.timerMinute.textContent = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      seconds++;
    };

    tick();
    return setInterval(tick, 1000);
  }
}

new Stopwatch().timer();
```

```html
<div class="text"></div>
<div>
  <span class="minute"></span>:<span class="second"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why, not just post code?

Comment: @Barmar better?

Answer (score 1):

This is nice and simple:

```js
var seconds = 0;
setInterval(function(){
 tick(document.getElementById("timer"), ++seconds);
}, 1000);

function tick(ele, secs){
 ele.innerHTML = Math.floor(secs / 60) + ":" + (secs % 60 < 10 ? "0" : "") + secs % 60;
}
```

```html
<span id="timer">0:00</span>
```

`Math.floor(secs / 60)` gives us the minutes and excludes any remainder of seconds, `secs % 60` gives us the remainder of seconds after we've divided by 60 (so it essentially removes the minutes), and `(secs % 60 < 10 ? "0" : "")` gives us a leading "0" if the seconds (excluding whole minutes) is less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how to make a counter that counts down from 60 (or any other number) and display it on the page.

```js
// Reference to html element that holds the count
const counterDiv = document.getElementById('counter');
// Variable that will keep track of the seconds to count down from
const secondsToCount = 60;
// Set the initial value of the counter to the secondsToCount variable.
// The counter will be updated each 1000ms | 1s and will be changed
// to the value of the remaining seconds to count down from
// which is why this variable is let opposed to const
let counter = secondsToCount;
// Set the initial text of the counter html element
counterDiv.innerHTML = secondsToCount;

// Function that is going to do counting for us.
const interval = setInterval( () => {
  // Decrement the current counter value by 1
  counter--;
  // Update the text to show the new value of our counter
  counterDiv.innerHTML = counter;
  // If the counter is === 0, the counter is finished. She some text.
  if (counter === 0) {
    // Clear the interval (otherwise, you'll continue to count
    // into the negative numbers
    clearInterval(interval);
    // Show the completed text
    counterDiv.innerHTML = `Done counting down from ${secondsToCount} seconds`;
  }

}, 1000); // 1000 ms | 1s
```

```html
<!-- Element used to show the count -->
<div id="counter"></div>
```